# How to use the Modx @EVAL binding in a Resource List TV's Parents field?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Exactly as the title says, I am trying to use an @EVAL binding to create a dynamic list of parent resources depending on the current context.  According to the docs it should be:

```
@EVAL return $modx->runSnippet('testSnipett');
```

But that is not working,  for testing purposes all I have in the snippett is:

```
<?php
$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'Test snipett running');
echo 201;
return 201;
```

nothing happens, nothing gets logged either - which I would expect if the script gets executed.

Anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: It looks valid enough for me - are you sure there's no typo in the snippet name?

Comment: checked and double checked - the nly thing I have not looked for is to see if modx will actually apply bindings on that field.  I also tried an @CHUNK binding without success!

Comment: Ah, yeah that's probably it. I think only the input options field support bindings and maybe the default.